# Puppeteer 'Page.getFrameTree' wasn't found undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Receiving

> error : Protocol error (Page.getFrameTree): 'Page.getFrameTree' wasn't found undefined

When attempting to run use puppeteer in chrome (also not headless), it works if executablePath is removed. Note also (for some reason) disable infobars isn't working in chrome & neither is setting the viewport

Versions of Things

> node v8.9.3
>
> Chrome Version 63.0.3239.84
>
> puppeteer v 0.13.0
>
> OS: Windows 10 Pro

For the following code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

puppeteer.launch(options = {
args: ['--disable-infobars']
});
// ^ Also not working.
(async() => {

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ['--remote-debugging-port=9222'],
    executablePath: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
    setViewport: {width: 1920, height: 1080},
});
// ^ Viewport also isn't working

try{
    const gitPage = await browser.newPage();
    await gitPage.setViewport({width: 1024, height: 768});
    await gitPage.goto("https://github.com/login", {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await gitPage.type("#login_field", "CaptainPlanet", {delay: 100});
    await gitPage.type("#password", "NPH_Andrews", {delay: 100});
    const btnLogin = await gitPage.$("input[tabindex='3']");
    await btnLogin.click();
}catch(err) {
  console.log("error: " + err.message);
}    


})();
```

Comment: The working tab functionality is available on beta (Chrome... 64?) but even still the info-bars remain at the top even with args: ['--disable-infobars']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurs when using the wrong version of chromium.

The release notes have the version of chromium you need to run, in your case:

Chromium 64.0.3264.0 (r515411)

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/releases